# strftime crashing joomla on php5

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to modify a part of Joomla 1.0 setup running on PHP 5.1.6 and I'm having problem with `strftime()` function. In the code I'm calling:

```
print strftime("%d-%m-%y", '1304184490') . "\n";
```

which works in a separate .php file just fine. When it's part of the joomla code, the script stops execution exactly on that line. I do not get any message in error log (got error_reporting set to E_ALL), no exception is generated, script just stops on that line (verified with `print "foo\n"` before and after).

What can be the cause of this? I'm not sure about the whole host configuration since it's some shared hosting account.

Comment: is that the entire code on that line ? What's the line before it?

Comment: @Khez Before and after it, there's only `print "foo\n";`. Only the first one works. That's the whole function in a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`strftime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) relies on the underlying C library to perform the formatting.  The manual warns:

> Not all conversion specifiers may be supported by your C library, in which case they will not be supported by PHP's strftime(). [...] This means that [various things] will not work on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating systems.

Now, your format string is pretty darn elementary, so there's no real reason that there should be a failure here.

Honestly, your best bet might be using the PHP-native function [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) instead of `strftime`, as `date` doesn't rely on a C library call.  The equivalent call would be:

```
echo date("d-m-y", '1304184490') . "\n";
```

Comment: It behaves in the same way. It works in a separate file, but when run within joomla code it stops execution without any errors logged.

Comment: @viraptor, that's deeply troubling.  Do other PHP functions work?  Can you show us more context in the file that is crashing?

Comment: @Charles: I think I've found a reason. If I set the zone with `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London')`, everything works fine. If I don't, `date_default_timezone_get()` itself stops the script (also no error log). Joomla version is "1.0.12". Timezone db version "0.system". Default timezone "Europe/London". date.timezone "no value". (values as reported by phpinfo())

Comment: @viraptor, I find that to be exceptionally odd.  You *do* have to have a default timezone set, but it's not a fatal error, it's just a warning.  Further, I'd expect that *something* before your code runs would have invoked a date function, right?

Comment: @Charles I add my custom file in, so the only joomla-init related things I do before the `...timezone_get()` is: `define('_VALID_MOS', 1); require('globals.php'); require_once('configuration.php'); require_once('includes/joomla.php');`

Comment: @viraptor, that's even *more* odd, then!  What happens if you reset `error_reporting` and enable `display_errors` after including the Joomla bootstrap?

Comment: @Charles I set log_errors=1, display_errors=1, error_reporting=E_ALL after the joomla requires. No changes at all. Yes, it's really bizarre.

Comment: @viraptor, I'm out of troubleshooting steps, unfortunately.  At this point, I'd usually suggest hooking up a debugger like xdebug, but that's not going to be possible on shared hosting.